# Heroku Ruby Version 2.7.0 due to Aptfile

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I need aptfile for vips, but when installing vips it seems to install ruby 2.7.0 although I require ruby 3.1.0 which is in the Gemfile and Gemfile.lock. I have tried adding ruby3.1.0 to Aptfile but doesn't have package, when adding ruby-full to Aptfile ruby 2.7.0 is installed.

Aptfile

```
libvips
```

Gemfile

```
source "https://rubygems.org"
git_source(:github) { |repo| "https://github.com/#{repo}.git" }

ruby "3.1.0"

# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem "rails", github: "rails/rails", branch: "main"
gem "rails", "~> 7.0.3"

# The original asset pipeline for Rails [https://github.com/rails/sprockets-rails]
gem "sprockets-rails"

# Use postgresql as the database for Active Record
gem "pg", "~> 1.1"
gem 'spina', '~> 2.2'
# Use the Puma web server [https://github.com/puma/puma]
gem "puma", "~> 5.0"
gem "ruby-vips"
# Use JavaScript with ESM import maps [https://github.com/rails/importmap-rails]
gem "importmap-rails"

# Hotwire's SPA-like page accelerator [https://turbo.hotwired.dev]
gem "turbo-rails"

# Hotwire's modest JavaScript framework [https://stimulus.hotwired.dev]
gem "stimulus-rails"

# Build JSON APIs with ease [https://github.com/rails/jbuilder]
gem "jbuilder"

# Use Redis adapter to run Action Cable in production
# gem "redis", "~> 4.0"

# Use Kredis to get higher-level data types in Redis [https://github.com/rails/kredis]
# gem "kredis"

# Use Active Model has_secure_password [https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_model_basics.html#securepassword]
# gem "bcrypt", "~> 3.1.7"

# Windows does not include zoneinfo files, so bundle the tzinfo-data gem
gem "tzinfo-data", platforms: %i[ mingw mswin x64_mingw jruby ]

# Reduces boot times through caching; required in config/boot.rb
gem "bootsnap", require: false

# Use Sass to process CSS
# gem "sassc-rails"

# Use Active Storage variants [https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_storage_overview.html#transforming-images]
# gem "image_processing", "~> 1.2"


gem 'google-webfonts', require: 'google/webfonts/rails'
gem "haml-rails", "~> 2.0"
group :development do
  # Use console on exceptions pages [https://github.com/rails/web-console]
  gem "web-console"

  # Add speed badges [https://github.com/MiniProfiler/rack-mini-profiler]
  # gem "rack-mini-profiler"

  # Speed up commands on slow machines / big apps [https://github.com/rails/spring]
  # gem "spring"
end

group :test do
  # Use system testing [https://guides.rubyonrails.org/testing.html#system-testing]
  gem "capybara"
  gem "selenium-webdriver"
  gem "webdrivers"
end
```

Gemfile.lock

```
GEM
  remote: https://rubygems.org/
  specs:
    actioncable (7.0.3)
      actionpack (= 7.0.3)
      activesupport (= 7.0.3)
      nio4r (~> 2.0)
      websocket-driver (>= 0.6.1)
    actionmailbox (7.0.3)
      actionpack (= 7.0.3)
      activejob (= 7.0.3)
      activerecord (= 7.0.3)
      activestorage (= 7.0.3)
      activesupport (= 7.0.3)
      mail (>= 2.7.1)
      net-imap
      net-pop
      net-smtp
    actionmailer (7.0.3)
      actionpack (= 7.0.3)
      actionview (= 7.0.3)
      activejob (= 7.0.3)
      activesupport (= 7.0.3)
      mail (~> 2.5, >= 2.5.4)
      net-imap
      net-pop
      net-smtp
      rails-dom-testing (~> 2.0)
    actionpack (7.0.3)
      actionview (= 7.0.3)
      activesupport (= 7.0.3)
      rack (~> 2.0, >= 2.2.0)
      rack-test (>= 0.6.3)
      rails-dom-testing (~> 2.0)
      rails-html-sanitizer (~> 1.0, >= 1.2.0)
    actiontext (7.0.3)
      actionpack (= 7.0.3)
      activerecord (= 7.0.3)
      activestorage (= 7.0.3)
      activesupport (= 7.0.3)
      globalid (>= 0.6.0)
      nokogiri (>= 1.8.5)
    actionview (7.0.3)
      activesupport (= 7.0.3)
      builder (~> 3.1)
      erubi (~> 1.4)
      rails-dom-testing (~> 2.0)
      rails-html-sanitizer (~> 1.1, >= 1.2.0)
    activejob (7.0.3)
      activesupport (= 7.0.3)
      globalid (>= 0.3.6)
    activemodel (7.0.3)
      activesupport (= 7.0.3)
    activerecord (7.0.3)
      activemodel (= 7.0.3)
      activesupport (= 7.0.3)
    activestorage (7.0.3)
      actionpack (= 7.0.3)
      activejob (= 7.0.3)
      activerecord (= 7.0.3)
      activesupport (= 7.0.3)
      marcel (~> 1.0)
      mini_mime (>= 1.1.0)
    activesupport (7.0.3)
      concurrent-ruby (~> 1.0, >= 1.0.2)
      i18n (>= 1.6, < 2)
      minitest (>= 5.1)
      tzinfo (~> 2.0)
    addressable (2.8.0)
      public_suffix (>= 2.0.2, < 5.0)
    ancestry (4.1.0)
      activerecord (>= 5.2.6)
    attr_json (1.4.0)
      activerecord (>= 5.0.0, < 7.1)
    babosa (2.0.0)
    bcrypt (3.1.18)
    bindex (0.8.1)
    bootsnap (1.11.1)
      msgpack (~> 1.2)
    breadcrumbs_on_rails (4.1.0)
      railties (>= 5.0)
    browser (5.3.1)
    builder (3.2.4)
    capybara (3.37.1)
      addressable
      matrix
      mini_mime (>= 0.1.3)
      nokogiri (~> 1.8)
      rack (>= 1.6.0)
      rack-test (>= 0.6.3)
      regexp_parser (>= 1.5, < 3.0)
      xpath (~> 3.2)
    childprocess (4.1.0)
    concurrent-ruby (1.1.10)
    crass (1.0.6)
    digest (3.1.0)
    erubi (1.10.0)
    erubis (2.7.0)
    ffi (1.15.5)
    globalid (1.0.0)
      activesupport (>= 5.0)
    google-webfonts (0.3.2)
    haml (5.2.2)
      temple (>= 0.8.0)
      tilt
    haml-rails (2.0.1)
      actionpack (>= 5.1)
      activesupport (>= 5.1)
      haml (>= 4.0.6, < 6.0)
      html2haml (>= 1.0.1)
      railties (>= 5.1)
    html2haml (2.2.0)
      erubis (~> 2.7.0)
      haml (>= 4.0, < 6)
      nokogiri (>= 1.6.0)
      ruby_parser (~> 3.5)
    i18n (1.10.0)
      concurrent-ruby (~> 1.0)
    image_processing (1.12.2)
      mini_magick (>= 4.9.5, < 5)
      ruby-vips (>= 2.0.17, < 3)
    importmap-rails (1.1.0)
      actionpack (>= 6.0.0)
      railties (>= 6.0.0)
    jbuilder (2.11.5)
      actionview (>= 5.0.0)
      activesupport (>= 5.0.0)
    jsonapi-serializer (2.2.0)
      activesupport (>= 4.2)
    kaminari (1.2.2)
      activesupport (>= 4.1.0)
      kaminari-actionview (= 1.2.2)
      kaminari-activerecord (= 1.2.2)
      kaminari-core (= 1.2.2)
    kaminari-actionview (1.2.2)
      actionview
      kaminari-core (= 1.2.2)
    kaminari-activerecord (1.2.2)
      activerecord
      kaminari-core (= 1.2.2)
    kaminari-core (1.2.2)
    loofah (2.18.0)
      crass (~> 1.0.2)
      nokogiri (>= 1.5.9)
    mail (2.7.1)
      mini_mime (>= 0.1.1)
    marcel (1.0.2)
    matrix (0.4.2)
    method_source (1.0.0)
    mini_magick (4.11.0)
    mini_mime (1.1.2)
    minitest (5.15.0)
    mobility (1.2.6)
      i18n (>= 0.6.10, < 2)
      request_store (~> 1.0)
    msgpack (1.5.1)
    net-imap (0.2.3)
      digest
      net-protocol
      strscan
    net-pop (0.1.1)
      digest
      net-protocol
      timeout
    net-protocol (0.1.3)
      timeout
    net-smtp (0.3.1)
      digest
      net-protocol
      timeout
    nio4r (2.5.8)
    nokogiri (1.13.6-arm64-darwin)
      racc (~> 1.4)
    nokogiri (1.13.6-x86_64-linux)
      racc (~> 1.4)
    pg (1.3.5)
    public_suffix (4.0.7)
    puma (5.6.4)
      nio4r (~> 2.0)
    racc (1.6.0)
    rack (2.2.3)
    rack-rewrite (1.5.1)
    rack-test (1.1.0)
      rack (>= 1.0, < 3)
    rails (7.0.3)
      actioncable (= 7.0.3)
      actionmailbox (= 7.0.3)
      actionmailer (= 7.0.3)
      actionpack (= 7.0.3)
      actiontext (= 7.0.3)
      actionview (= 7.0.3)
      activejob (= 7.0.3)
      activemodel (= 7.0.3)
      activerecord (= 7.0.3)
      activestorage (= 7.0.3)
      activesupport (= 7.0.3)
      bundler (>= 1.15.0)
      railties (= 7.0.3)
    rails-dom-testing (2.0.3)
      activesupport (>= 4.2.0)
      nokogiri (>= 1.6)
    rails-html-sanitizer (1.4.2)
      loofah (~> 2.3)
    railties (7.0.3)
      actionpack (= 7.0.3)
      activesupport (= 7.0.3)
      method_source
      rake (>= 12.2)
      thor (~> 1.0)
      zeitwerk (~> 2.5)
    rake (13.0.6)
    regexp_parser (2.4.0)
    request_store (1.5.1)
      rack (>= 1.4)
    rexml (3.2.5)
    ruby-vips (2.1.4)
      ffi (~> 1.12)
    ruby_parser (3.19.1)
      sexp_processor (~> 4.16)
    rubyzip (2.3.2)
    selenium-webdriver (4.1.0)
      childprocess (>= 0.5, < 5.0)
      rexml (~> 3.2, >= 3.2.5)
      rubyzip (>= 1.2.2)
    sexp_processor (4.16.1)
    spina (2.10.0)
      ancestry
      attr_json
      babosa
      bcrypt
      breadcrumbs_on_rails
      browser
      image_processing
      importmap-rails (>= 0.7.6)
      jsonapi-serializer
      kaminari
      mobility (>= 1.1.3)
      pg
      rack-rewrite (>= 1.5.0)
      rails (>= 6.0)
      sprockets-rails
      stimulus-rails (>= 0.7.0)
      tailwindcss-rails (>= 2.0.0)
      turbo-rails (>= 0.9, < 2.0)
      view_component (~> 2.32)
    sprockets (4.0.3)
      concurrent-ruby (~> 1.0)
      rack (> 1, < 3)
    sprockets-rails (3.4.2)
      actionpack (>= 5.2)
      activesupport (>= 5.2)
      sprockets (>= 3.0.0)
    stimulus-rails (1.0.4)
      railties (>= 6.0.0)
    strscan (3.0.3)
    tailwindcss-rails (2.0.8-arm64-darwin)
      railties (>= 6.0.0)
    tailwindcss-rails (2.0.8-x86_64-linux)
      railties (>= 6.0.0)
    temple (0.8.2)
    thor (1.2.1)
    tilt (2.0.10)
    timeout (0.3.0)
    turbo-rails (1.1.1)
      actionpack (>= 6.0.0)
      activejob (>= 6.0.0)
      railties (>= 6.0.0)
    tzinfo (2.0.4)
      concurrent-ruby (~> 1.0)
    view_component (2.55.0)
      activesupport (>= 5.0.0, < 8.0)
      method_source (~> 1.0)
    web-console (4.2.0)
      actionview (>= 6.0.0)
      activemodel (>= 6.0.0)
      bindex (>= 0.4.0)
      railties (>= 6.0.0)
    webdrivers (5.0.0)
      nokogiri (~> 1.6)
      rubyzip (>= 1.3.0)
      selenium-webdriver (~> 4.0)
    websocket-driver (0.7.5)
      websocket-extensions (>= 0.1.0)
    websocket-extensions (0.1.5)
    xpath (3.2.0)
      nokogiri (~> 1.8)
    zeitwerk (2.5.4)

PLATFORMS
  arm64-darwin-21
  x86_64-linux

DEPENDENCIES
  bootsnap
  capybara
  google-webfonts
  haml-rails (~> 2.0)
  importmap-rails
  jbuilder
  pg (~> 1.1)
  puma (~> 5.0)
  rails (~> 7.0.3)
  ruby-vips
  selenium-webdriver
  spina (~> 2.2)
  sprockets-rails
  stimulus-rails
  turbo-rails
  tzinfo-data
  web-console
  webdrivers

RUBY VERSION
   ruby 3.1.0p0

BUNDLED WITH
   2.3.3
```

Log push to heroku:

```
Run git push heroku main to create a new release using this buildpack.
❯ git push heroku main
Enumerating objects: 201, done.
Counting objects: 100% (201/201), done.
Delta compression using up to 8 threads
Compressing objects: 100% (172/172), done.
Writing objects: 100% (201/201), 1.38 MiB | 1.35 MiB/s, done.
Total 201 (delta 27), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 0
remote: Compressing source files... done.
remote: Building source:
remote:
remote: -----> Building on the Heroku-20 stack
remote: -----> Using buildpack: heroku-community/apt
remote: -----> Apt app detected
remote: -----> Detected Aptfile or Stack changes, flushing cache
remote: -----> Updating apt caches
remote:        Get:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal InRelease [265 kB]
remote:        Get:2 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security InRelease [114 kB]
remote:        Get:3 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates InRelease [114 kB]
remote:        Get:4 http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt focal-pgdg InRelease [91.7 kB]
remote:        Get:5 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/main amd64 Packages [1,275 kB]
remote:        Get:6 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/universe amd64 Packages [11.3 MB]
remote:        Get:7 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security/main amd64 Packages [1,839 kB]
remote:        Get:8 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security/universe amd64 Packages [874 kB]
remote:        Get:9 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/universe amd64 Packages [1,161 kB]
remote:        Get:10 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 Packages [2,272 kB]
remote:        Get:11 http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt focal-pgdg/main amd64 Packages [384 kB]
remote:        Fetched 19.7 MB in 2s (11.9 MB/s)
remote:        Reading package lists...
remote: -----> Fetching .debs for libvips
remote:        Reading package lists...
remote:        Building dependency tree...
remote:        The following additional packages will be installed:
remote:          adwaita-icon-theme alsa-topology-conf alsa-ucm-conf at-spi2-core dbus
remote:          dbus-user-session dconf-gsettings-backend dconf-service dmsetup firefox
remote:          glib-networking glib-networking-common glib-networking-services
remote:          gsettings-desktop-schemas gtk-update-icon-cache humanity-icon-theme libaec0
remote:          libapparmor1 libasound2 libasound2-data libatk-bridge2.0-0 libatk1.0-0
remote:          libatk1.0-data libatspi2.0-0 libcanberra0 libcdt5 libcfitsio8 libcgraph6
remote:          libcolord2 libcryptsetup12 libdbus-glib-1-2 libdbusmenu-glib4
remote:          libdbusmenu-gtk3-4 libdconf1 libdevmapper1.02.1 libepoxy0 libgail-common
remote:          libgail18 libgfortran5 libgif7 libgsf-1-114 libgsf-1-common libgsl23
remote:          libgslcblas0 libgtk-3-0 libgtk-3-bin libgtk-3-common libgtk2.0-0
remote:          libgtk2.0-bin libgtk2.0-common libgts-0.7-5 libgts-bin libgvc6 libhdf5-103
remote:          libimagequant0 libip4tc2 libjson-glib-1.0-0 libjson-glib-1.0-common
remote:          libmatio9 libnspr4 libnss-systemd libnss3 libogg0 libopenslide0 liborc-0.4-0
remote:          libpam-systemd libpathplan4 libpoppler-glib8 libpoppler97 libproxy1v5
remote:          librest-0.7-0 libsoup-gnome2.4-1 libsoup2.4-1 libsz2 libtdb1 libvorbis0a
remote:          libvorbisfile3 libwayland-client0 libwayland-cursor0 libwayland-egl1
remote:          libx11-xcb1 libxcomposite1 libxcursor1 libxdamage1 libxfixes3 libxi6
remote:          libxinerama1 libxkbcommon0 libxrandr2 libxtst6 networkd-dispatcher nip2
remote:          python3-dbus python3-gi sound-theme-freedesktop systemd systemd-sysv
remote:          systemd-timesyncd ubuntu-mono xkb-data xul-ext-ubufox
remote:        Suggested packages:
remote:          fonts-lyx libasound2-plugins alsa-utils libcanberra-gtk0 libcanberra-pulse
remote:          colord gsl-ref-psdoc | gsl-doc-pdf | gsl-doc-info | gsl-ref-html gvfs iw
remote:          | wireless-tools libvips-doc libvips-tools python-dbus-doc python3-dbus-dbg
remote:          systemd-container policykit-1
remote:        The following NEW packages will be installed:
remote:          adwaita-icon-theme alsa-topology-conf alsa-ucm-conf at-spi2-core dbus
remote:          dbus-user-session dconf-gsettings-backend dconf-service dmsetup firefox
remote:          glib-networking glib-networking-common glib-networking-services
remote:          gsettings-desktop-schemas gtk-update-icon-cache humanity-icon-theme libaec0
remote:          libapparmor1 libasound2 libasound2-data libatk-bridge2.0-0 libatk1.0-0
remote:          libatk1.0-data libatspi2.0-0 libcanberra0 libcdt5 libcfitsio8 libcgraph6
remote:          libcolord2 libcryptsetup12 libdbus-glib-1-2 libdbusmenu-glib4
remote:          libdbusmenu-gtk3-4 libdconf1 libdevmapper1.02.1 libepoxy0 libgail-common
remote:          libgail18 libgfortran5 libgif7 libgsf-1-114 libgsf-1-common libgsl23
remote:          libgslcblas0 libgtk-3-0 libgtk-3-bin libgtk-3-common libgtk2.0-0
remote:          libgtk2.0-bin libgtk2.0-common libgts-0.7-5 libgts-bin libgvc6 libhdf5-103
remote:          libimagequant0 libip4tc2 libjson-glib-1.0-0 libjson-glib-1.0-common
remote:          libmatio9 libnspr4 libnss-systemd libnss3 libogg0 libopenslide0 liborc-0.4-0
remote:          libpam-systemd libpathplan4 libpoppler-glib8 libpoppler97 libproxy1v5
remote:          librest-0.7-0 libsoup-gnome2.4-1 libsoup2.4-1 libsz2 libtdb1 libvips42
remote:          libvorbis0a libvorbisfile3 libwayland-client0 libwayland-cursor0
remote:          libwayland-egl1 libx11-xcb1 libxcomposite1 libxcursor1 libxdamage1
remote:          libxfixes3 libxi6 libxinerama1 libxkbcommon0 libxrandr2 libxtst6
remote:          networkd-dispatcher nip2 python3-dbus python3-gi sound-theme-freedesktop
remote:          systemd systemd-sysv systemd-timesyncd ubuntu-mono xkb-data xul-ext-ubufox
remote:        0 upgraded, 102 newly installed, 0 to remove and 3 not upgraded.
remote:        Need to get 88.9 MB of archives.
remote:        After this operation, 363 MB of additional disk space will be used.
remote:        Get:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 libapparmor1 amd64 2.13.3-7ubuntu5.1 [34.1 kB]
remote:        Get:2 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/main amd64 libdevmapper1.02.1 amd64 2:1.02.167-1ubuntu1 [127 kB]
remote:        Get:3 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security/main amd64 libcryptsetup12 amd64 2:2.2.2-3ubuntu2.4 [166 kB]
remote:        Get:4 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/main amd64 libip4tc2 amd64 1.8.4-3ubuntu2 [18.8 kB]
0917-0ubuntu6 [27.7 kB]
remote:        Get:74 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/main amd64 libgtk2.0-common all 2.24.32-4ubuntu4 [126 kB]
remote:        Get:75 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/main amd64 libgtk2.0-0 amd64 2.24.32-4ubuntu4 [1,791 kB]
remote:        Get:76 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/main amd64 libgail18 amd64 2.24.32-4ubuntu4 [14.7 kB]
remote:        Get:77 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/main amd64 libgail-common amd64 2.24.32-4ubuntu4 [116 kB]
remote:        Get:78 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security/main amd64 libgfortran5 amd64 10.3.0-1ubuntu1~20.04 [736 kB]
remote:        Get:79 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/main amd64 libgif7 amd64 5.1.9-1 [32.2 kB]
remote:        Get:80 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/main amd64 libgsf-1-common all 1.14.46-1 [12.7 kB]
remote:        Get:81 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/main amd64 libgsf-1-114 amd64 1.14.46-1 [98.3 kB]
remote:        Get:82 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/universe amd64 libgslcblas0 amd64 2.5+dfsg-6build1 [84.6 kB]
remote:        Get:83 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/universe amd64 libgsl23 amd64 2.5+dfsg-6build1 [850 kB]
remote:        Get:84 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 libgtk-3-bin amd64 3.24.20-0ubuntu1.1 [61.9 kB]
remote:        Get:85 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/main amd64 libgtk2.0-bin amd64 2.24.32-4ubuntu4 [7,728 B]
remote:        Get:86 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/universe amd64 libgts-0.7-5 amd64 0.7.6+darcs121130-4 [150 kB]
remote:        Get:87 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/universe amd64 libgts-bin amd64 0.7.6+darcs121130-4 [41.3 kB]
remote:        Get:88 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/universe amd64 libpathplan4 amd64 2.42.2-3build2 [21.9 kB]
remote:        Get:89 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/universe amd64 libgvc6 amd64 2.42.2-3build2 [647 kB]
remote:        Get:90 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/universe amd64 libsz2 amd64 1.0.4-1 [5,188 B]
remote:        Get:91 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/universe amd64 libhdf5-103 amd64 1.10.4+repack-11ubuntu1 [1,311 kB]
remote:        Get:92 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/main amd64 libimagequant0 amd64 2.12.2-1.1 [31.4 kB]
remote:        Get:93 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/universe amd64 libmatio9 amd64 1.5.17-3 [93.6 kB]
remote:        Get:94 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/main amd64 libnspr4 amd64 2:4.25-1 [107 kB]
remote:        Get:95 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security/main amd64 libnss3 amd64 2:3.49.1-1ubuntu1.7 [1,256 kB]
remote:        Get:96 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/universe amd64 libopenslide0 amd64 3.4.1+dfsg-4 [82.1 kB]
remote:        Get:97 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/main amd64 liborc-0.4-0 amd64 1:0.4.31-1 [188 kB]
remote:        Get:98 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/main amd64 libpoppler97 amd64 0.86.1-0ubuntu1 [915 kB]
remote:        Get:99 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/main amd64 libpoppler-glib8 amd64 0.86.1-0ubuntu1 [109 kB]
remote:        Get:100 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/universe amd64 libvips42 amd64 8.9.1-2 [1,040 kB]
remote:        Get:101 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/universe amd64 nip2 amd64 8.7.0-1 [4,609 kB]
remote:        Get:102 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/main amd64 xul-ext-ubufox all 3.4-0ubuntu1.17.10.1 [3,320 B]
remote:        Fetched 88.9 MB in 4s (22.3 MB/s)
remote:        Download complete and in download only mode
remote: -----> Installing adwaita-icon-theme_3.36.1-2ubuntu0.20.04.2_all.deb
remote: -----> Installing alsa-topology-conf_1.2.2-1_all.deb
remote: -----> Installing alsa-ucm-conf_1.2.2-1ubuntu0.13_all.deb
remote: -----> Installing at-spi2-core_2.36.0-2_amd64.deb
remote: -----> Installing dbus_1.12.16-2ubuntu2.2_amd64.deb
remote: -----> Installing dbus-user-session_1.12.16-2ubuntu2.2_amd64.deb
remote: -----> Installing dconf-gsettings-backend_0.36.0-1_amd64.deb
remote: -----> Installing dconf-service_0.36.0-1_amd64.deb
remote: -----> Installing dmsetup_2%3a1.02.167-1ubuntu1_amd64.deb
remote: -----> Installing firefox_100.0.2+build1-0ubuntu0.20.04.1_amd64.deb
 remote: -----> Installing glib-networking_2.64.2-1ubuntu0.1_amd64.deb
remote: -----> Installing glib-networking-common_2.64.2-1ubuntu0.1_all.deb
remote: -----> Installing glib-networking-services_2.64.2-1ubuntu0.1_amd64.deb
remote: -----> Installing gsettings-desktop-schemas_3.36.0-1ubuntu1_all.deb
remote: -----> Installing gtk-update-icon-cache_3.24.20-0ubuntu1.1_amd64.deb
remote: -----> Installing humanity-icon-theme_0.6.15_all.deb
remote: -----> Installing libaec0_1.0.4-1_amd64.deb
remote: -----> Installing libapparmor1_2.13.3-7ubuntu5.1_amd64.deb
remote: -----> Installing libasound2_1.2.2-2.1ubuntu2.5_amd64.deb
remote: -----> Installing libasound2-data_1.2.2-2.1ubuntu2.5_all.deb
remote: -----> Installing libatk1.0-0_2.35.1-1ubuntu2_amd64.deb
remote: -----> Installing libatk1.0-data_2.35.1-1ubuntu2_all.deb
remote: -----> Installing libatk-bridge2.0-0_2.34.2-0ubuntu2~20.04.1_amd64.deb
remote: -----> Installing libatspi2.0-0_2.36.0-2_amd64.deb
remote: -----> Installing libcanberra0_0.30-7ubuntu1_amd64.deb
remote: -----> Installing libcdt5_2.42.2-3build2_amd64.deb
remote: -----> Installing libcfitsio8_3.470-3_amd64.deb
remote: -----> Installing libcgraph6_2.42.2-3build2_amd64.deb
remote: -----> Installing libcolord2_1.4.4-2_amd64.deb
remote: -----> Installing libcryptsetup12_2%3a2.2.2-3ubuntu2.4_amd64.deb
remote: -----> Installing libdbus-glib-1-2_0.110-5fakssync1_amd64.deb
remote: -----> Installing libdbusmenu-glib4_16.04.1+18.10.20180917-0ubuntu6_amd64.deb
remote: -----> Installing libdbusmenu-gtk3-4_16.04.1+18.10.20180917-0ubuntu6_amd64.deb
remote: -----> Installing libdconf1_0.36.0-1_amd64.deb
remote: -----> Installing libdevmapper1.02.1_2%3a1.02.167-1ubuntu1_amd64.deb
remote: -----> Installing libepoxy0_1.5.4-1_amd64.deb
remote: -----> Installing libgail18_2.24.32-4ubuntu4_amd64.deb
remote: -----> Installing libgail-common_2.24.32-4ubuntu4_amd64.deb
remote: -----> Installing libgfortran5_10.3.0-1ubuntu1~20.04_amd64.deb
remote: -----> Installing libgif7_5.1.9-1_amd64.deb
remote: -----> Installing libgsf-1-114_1.14.46-1_amd64.deb
remote: -----> Installing libgsf-1-common_1.14.46-1_all.deb
remote: -----> Installing libgsl23_2.5+dfsg-6build1_amd64.deb
remote: -----> Installing libgslcblas0_2.5+dfsg-6build1_amd64.deb
remote: -----> Installing libgtk2.0-0_2.24.32-4ubuntu4_amd64.deb
remote: -----> Installing libgtk2.0-bin_2.24.32-4ubuntu4_amd64.deb
remote: -----> Installing libgtk2.0-common_2.24.32-4ubuntu4_all.deb
remote: -----> Installing libgtk-3-0_3.24.20-0ubuntu1.1_amd64.deb
remote: -----> Installing libgtk-3-bin_3.24.20-0ubuntu1.1_amd64.deb
remote: -----> Installing libgtk-3-common_3.24.20-0ubuntu1.1_all.deb
remote: -----> Installing libgts-0.7-5_0.7.6+darcs121130-4_amd64.deb
remote: -----> Installing libgts-bin_0.7.6+darcs121130-4_amd64.deb
remote: -----> Installing libgvc6_2.42.2-3build2_amd64.deb
remote: -----> Installing libhdf5-103_1.10.4+repack-11ubuntu1_amd64.deb
remote: -----> Installing libimagequant0_2.12.2-1.1_amd64.deb
remote: -----> Installing libip4tc2_1.8.4-3ubuntu2_amd64.deb
remote: -----> Installing libjson-glib-1.0-0_1.4.4-2ubuntu2_amd64.deb
remote: -----> Installing libjson-glib-1.0-common_1.4.4-2ubuntu2_all.deb
remote: -----> Installing libmatio9_1.5.17-3_amd64.deb
remote: -----> Installing libnspr4_2%3a4.25-1_amd64.deb
remote: -----> Installing libnss3_2%3a3.49.1-1ubuntu1.7_amd64.deb
remote: -----> Installing libnss-systemd_245.4-4ubuntu3.17_amd64.deb
remote: -----> Installing libogg0_1.3.4-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb
remote: -----> Installing libopenslide0_3.4.1+dfsg-4_amd64.deb
remote: -----> Installing liborc-0.4-0_1%3a0.4.31-1_amd64.deb
remote: -----> Installing libpam-systemd_245.4-4ubuntu3.17_amd64.deb
remote: -----> Installing libpathplan4_2.42.2-3build2_amd64.deb
remote: -----> Installing libpoppler97_0.86.1-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb
remote: -----> Installing libpoppler-glib8_0.86.1-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb
remote: -----> Installing libproxy1v5_0.4.15-10ubuntu1.2_amd64.deb
remote: -----> Installing librest-0.7-0_0.8.1-1_amd64.deb
remote: -----> Installing libsoup2.4-1_2.70.0-1_amd64.deb
remote: -----> Installing libsoup-gnome2.4-1_2.70.0-1_amd64.deb
remote: -----> Installing libsz2_1.0.4-1_amd64.deb
remote: -----> Installing libtdb1_1.4.3-0ubuntu0.20.04.1_amd64.deb
remote: -----> Installing libvips42_8.9.1-2_amd64.deb
remote: -----> Installing libvorbis0a_1.3.6-2ubuntu1_amd64.deb
remote: -----> Installing libvorbisfile3_1.3.6-2ubuntu1_amd64.deb
remote: -----> Installing libwayland-client0_1.18.0-1_amd64.deb
remote: -----> Installing libwayland-cursor0_1.18.0-1_amd64.deb
remote: -----> Installing libwayland-egl1_1.18.0-1_amd64.deb
remote: -----> Installing libx11-xcb1_2%3a1.6.9-2ubuntu1.2_amd64.deb
remote: -----> Installing libxcomposite1_1%3a0.4.5-1_amd64.deb
remote: -----> Installing libxcursor1_1%3a1.2.0-2_amd64.deb
remote: -----> Installing libxdamage1_1%3a1.1.5-2_amd64.deb
remote: -----> Installing libxfixes3_1%3a5.0.3-2_amd64.deb
remote: -----> Installing libxi6_2%3a1.7.10-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb
remote: -----> Installing libxinerama1_2%3a1.1.4-2_amd64.deb
remote: -----> Installing libxkbcommon0_0.10.0-1_amd64.deb
remote: -----> Installing libxrandr2_2%3a1.5.2-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb
remote: -----> Installing libxtst6_2%3a1.2.3-1_amd64.deb
remote: -----> Installing networkd-dispatcher_2.1-2~ubuntu20.04.3_all.deb
remote: -----> Installing nip2_8.7.0-1_amd64.deb
remote: -----> Installing python3-dbus_1.2.16-1build1_amd64.deb
remote: -----> Installing python3-gi_3.36.0-1_amd64.deb
remote: -----> Installing sound-theme-freedesktop_0.8-2ubuntu1_all.deb
remote: -----> Installing systemd_245.4-4ubuntu3.17_amd64.deb
remote: -----> Installing systemd-sysv_245.4-4ubuntu3.17_amd64.deb
remote: -----> Installing systemd-timesyncd_245.4-4ubuntu3.17_amd64.deb
remote: -----> Installing ubuntu-mono_19.04-0ubuntu3_all.deb
remote: -----> Installing xkb-data_2.29-2_all.deb
remote: -----> Installing xul-ext-ubufox_3.4-0ubuntu1.17.10.1_all.deb
remote: -----> Writing profile script
remote: -----> Rewrite package-config files
remote: -----> Discovering process types
remote:        Procfile declares types -> release, web
remote:
remote: -----> Compressing...
remote:        Done: 117.9M
remote: -----> Launching...
remote:  !     Release command declared: this new release will not be available until the command succeeds.
remote:        Released v3
remote:        https://devportalmain22.herokuapp.com/ deployed to Heroku
remote:
remote:  !
remote:  ! ## Warning - The same version of this code has already been built: 78095c83042ae210086dc7b08c28c2de9f5d08cd
remote:  !
remote:  ! We have detected that you have triggered a build from source code with version 78095c83042ae210086dc7b08c28c2de9f5d08cd
remote:  ! at least twice. One common cause of this behavior is attempting to deploy code from a different branch.
remote:  !
remote:  ! If you are developing on a branch and deploying via git you must run:
remote:  !
remote:  !     git push heroku <branchname>:main
remote:  !
remote:  ! This article goes into details on the behavior:
remote:  !   https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/duplicate-build-version
remote:
remote: Verifying deploy... done.
remote: Running release command...
remote:
remote: /usr/lib/ruby/2.7.0/bundler/definition.rb:495:in `validate_ruby!': Your Ruby version is 2.7.0, but your Gemfile specified 3.1.0 (Bundler::RubyVersionMismatch)
remote:     from /usr/lib/ruby/2.7.0/bundler/definition.rb:470:in `validate_runtime!'
remote:     from /usr/lib/ruby/2.7.0/bundler.rb:143:in `setup'
remote:     from /usr/lib/ruby/2.7.0/bundler/setup.rb:20:in `block in <top (required)>'
remote:     from /usr/lib/ruby/2.7.0/bundler/ui/shell.rb:136:in `with_level'
remote:     from /usr/lib/ruby/2.7.0/bundler/ui/shell.rb:88:in `silence'
remote:     from /usr/lib/ruby/2.7.0/bundler/setup.rb:20:in `<top (required)>'
remote:     from /usr/lib/ruby/2.7.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:92:in `require'
remote:     from /usr/lib/ruby/2.7.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:92:in `require'
remote:     from /app/config/boot.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
remote:     from bin/rake:2:in `require_relative'
remote:     from bin/rake:2:in `<main>'
remote: Waiting for release.... failed.
To https://git.heroku.com/ec-main
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem as you before. In my case adding buidpack heroku/ruby after heroku-buildpack-vips resoleve problem.